# How to automatically formatting date values entered into a column through a webhook on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am having a webhook enter date values on a google sheets column from Shopify. However, the values entered are not being read by google sheets as 'date' type, but as string type. Any ideas how they could automatically be converted to date type values as they are entered on to google sheets?[image]

Comment: I think that you would need to put more detail in how exactly are this values being inserted in your sheet. Are you using the API? Apps Script? Have you tried to simply format the format or `T` column?

Answer (score 0):

you can use formula to convert it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(T2:T; "Z"; ); "T"; " "))
```